Sequential Approach lower error than Simultaneous approach
I'm looking for a situation/code example and dataset (preferably 2 datasets), where the greedy/sequential approach has a lower cross-validation error than a simultaneous approach (where comparison is made on the same k-folds in the two cases).
Any examples/ideas for this? It doesn't need to be always true (simultaneous is usually better)--but any contrary example will work!
